# Intuition for the time/energy connection?

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws, symmetry, time, noethers-theorem

I find the following analogy reasonably intuitive:

> translational symmetry : conservation of linear momentum :: rotational symmetry : conservation of angular momentum

In contrast, I find the analogy below totally unexpected and difficult to rationalize:

> translational symmetry : conservation of linear momentum :: time symmetry : conservation of energy

(Both analogies come from Noether's theorem.)

I'm looking for ways make the second analogy somehow more intuitive.

Comment: Perhaps in the context of special relativity, when you think $(E/c, \vec{p})$ form a 4-vector and $(c t, \vec{x}) $ another and they can be considered classical conjugate variables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much this can be an "answer", as reasoning that makes something intuitive to one person doesn't necessarily make it intuitive to another. This is far from rigorous, but more of a pattern that you can maybe haphazardly apply to some success.

If you notice the symmetry transformation - conserved quantity when multiplied have the same units. The action has units of kg*m$^2$/s$^2$, translation times momentum gives (m) * (kg*m/s). If you are OK saying that angle "has no unit" then you get that ()*(kg*m$^2$/s$^2$), giving pretty good intuition on why angular momentum and action always have the same units.

So applying this intuition backwards the action divided by the units of time gives some quantity kg*m$^2$/s. We can go a little further if you notice that translations are a vector quantity and leads to a conserved vector quantity. This is a single transformation so it should lead to a single conserved quantity. So if time translation is a symmetry it should result in a scalar with units kg*m$^2$/s, which sounds a fair amount like an energy as opposed to a vector with those units (like a torque).

Really stretching this, the electric field has units (1/C)*kg*m$^2$ where C is Coulombs. The electric field is the gradient of the electric potential giving the units of $\Phi$ as (1/C)*kg*m$^2$/s$^2$. Gauge invariance tells us that we can shift the potential by the time derivative of a scalar function without changing the dynamics, meaning something with units (1/C)*kg*m$^2$/s. The combination of this shift with the conserved quantity should be equal to the units of action so something like (1/C)*kg*m$^2$/s * [Q] = kg * m$^2$ /s. This gives the conserved quantity [Q] units of Coloumbs. I don't want to claim anything super crazy here though, this just demonstrates that "there is a relationship between gauge symmetry and charge conservation" in a non-rigorous way.

Answer (score 0):

Seem the answer of mine is quite a late one for the Asker @TEH.

For coming freshman in Physics Exchange, I offer a metaphor associated with the intuition of the "time/energy conservation law" using a thought experiment in physics reality, framed in terms of a child's money jar:

Once upon a time, there was a kid named Timmy who had 10 bucks. in a jar. He wondered what would happen to his money over time evolution one day. He decided to embark on a little physics experiment.

- Doing nothing: After a day, he still had 10 bucks. Money (Energy) conserved when he didn't act something or give a “work” on it.
- Car washing: Timmy offered a car washing “work” to neighbors in one day, and earned 1 buck, ending the day with 11 bucks. Car washing “work” increased his money (Energy) of a time evolution one day.
- Enjoying Ice cream: He had a sweet tooth, spent 1 buck on ice cream and had 10 bucks left this time. Spending 1 buck dissipated his money (Energy) over time evolution one day.

Timmy learned that money, like Energy, conserves in time evolution if no “work” involved. He decided to earn more and make wise choices to grow his saving jar since then. And so, his Physics Exchange journey began.